# Are secondary launchers supported in Java 11?

Tags: java, maven, java-11

Iv'e been assigned the task of rebuilding an app originally create with Java 8 with Java 11. No code changes, just updates to the maven project file (pom.xml).

It's a self contained app (distributed with the java runtime). During the build process of current version - secondary launchers are being created (additional OS specific , native executables, created from the main codebase as part of the build process).

In Java 9 and 10 - secondary launchers were not supported on Mac OSx. 
Has anyone tried to produce secondary launchers in a Java 11 project ? I couldn't find anything in the official documentation or in Google.

Thanks

Comment: What is a "secondary launcher"?

Comment: If you are referring to [this library](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin), read at the very bottom: ***(Not yet) Release(d) Notes*** - *JDK 9 compatibility.* Considering that java9 isn't compatilbe I don't think java 11 is

Comment: Not using this specific lib. does not officially support Java 10 and 11. Thanks for the comment anyway.

Comment: The whole desktop story is a bit murky in Java right now. Java 11 removed support for tech like Webstart and JavaFX, and Java 8 seems to be the last version with these things (they made that an LTS version because of that).

Comment: Yes, JavaFX was removed but is maintained by external dev groups. Secondary launchers support was dropped only in Mac Osx, That's why I was hoping to see it back in the list of supported feature. I'll have to run a test on my own and verify. I'll report back here once I have a proper answer (and a working sample if it does).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As taken from Oracle docs for Java 10(
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/deploy/self-contained-application-packaging.htm#JSDPG996)  :

**Multiple entry points are supported only for Windows and Linux applications.** This is also true in Java 11.

The support for secondary launchers for Mac was dropped and is not expected to be back.